# Why this don't work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This Function is Work:

```
function son_bolum_liste_cek($limit)
{   
global $db;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `anime_bolum`.`id`, `anime`.`isim`, `anime_bolum`.`bolum_no`, `image`.`url` as `image`, `gifimage`.`url` as `gifimage` FROM `anime_bolum` JOIN `anime` ON `anime`.`id` = `anime_bolum`.`anime_id` JOIN `image` ON `anime_bolum`.`image` = `image`.`id` JOIN `image` as `gifimage` ON `gifimage`.`id` = `anime_bolum`.`gifimage` ORDER BY `anime_bolum`.`id` DESC LIMIT :limit;");
$query->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$select = $query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
}
foreach (son_bolum_liste_cek(12) as $anime){blabla};
```

But This is Don't Work:

```
function db_toplu_veri_oku($query, $execute = array() , $binds = array(),$debug = false)
{
global $db;
$query = $db->prepare($query);
foreach($binds as $bind)
    {
    $query->bindValue($bind[0], $bind[1], $bind[2]);
    }

$select = $query->execute($execute);
if($debug){$query->debugDumpParams();};
return $query->fetchAll();
}

function son_bolum_liste_cek($limit)
{   
$query = "SELECT `anime_bolum`.`id`, `anime`.`isim`, `anime_bolum`.`bolum_no`, `image`.`url` as `image`, `gifimage`.`url` as `gifimage` FROM `anime_bolum` JOIN `anime` ON `anime`.`id` = `anime_bolum`.`anime_id` JOIN `image` ON `anime_bolum`.`image` = `image`.`id` JOIN `image` as `gifimage` ON `gifimage`.`id` = `anime_bolum`.`gifimage` ORDER BY `anime_bolum`.`id` DESC LIMIT :limit;";
$binds = array(array(':limit',$limit,PDO::PARAM_INT));
return db_toplu_veri_oku($query,array(),$binds);
}
foreach (son_bolum_liste_cek(12) as $anime){blabla};
```

Two Function doing same work but bottom function don't work why ? Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Define "don't work".  What should it be doing and how specifically does it fail?

Comment: Bottom Function return empty array but upper dont return empty array. I want dont return empty array.(I can not tell myself in english :@@)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little change. Issue in `execute`. You are passing blank array in this. So you have to check first if array containing value or not

```
function db_toplu_veri_oku($query, $execute = array() , $binds = array(),$debug = false)
{
global $db;
$query = $db->prepare($query);
foreach($binds as $bind)
    {
    $query->bindValue($bind[0], $bind[1], $bind[2]);
    }

if(count($execute)) //<-----------Add this condition
    $select = $query->execute($execute);
else
    $select = $query->execute();
if($debug){$query->debugDumpParams();};
return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: thanks this is work !